# Elliptic Curve Cryptography implementation in Java 7

Tags: java

I am trying to implement Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC) in java as java 7 provides native provider SunEC which supports Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC)
But I am always getting an error java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key length: 91 bytes because the  Elliptic  curve 
I am creating is not appropriate.

I am using java 7 my task is to use ECC to generate key for encryption and decryption

```
package com.acc;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.EllipticCurve;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;


public class TestECC {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Provider p[] = Security.getProviders();
            Provider p1 = Security.getProvider("SunEC");
            System.out.println(p1.getName());
            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "SunEC");
            System.out.println(kpg.getAlgorithm());

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            System.out.println("provider=" + cipher.getProvider());

            ECGenParameterSpec ecsp = new ECGenParameterSpec("sect163r2");

            kpg.initialize(ecsp);
            KeyPair kyp = kpg.genKeyPair();
            PublicKey pubKey = kyp.getPublic();

            PrivateKey privKey = kyp.getPrivate();
            System.out.println(cipher.getProvider());

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

            String cleartextFile = "cleartext.txt";
            String ciphertextFile = "ciphertextECIES.txt";

            byte[] block = new byte[64];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cleartextFile);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ciphertextFile);
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

            int i;
            while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
                cos.write(block, 0, i);
            }
            cos.close();

            // Decrypt

            String cleartextAgainFile = "cleartextAgainECIES.txt";

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey, ecsp);

            fis = new FileInputStream(ciphertextFile);
            CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(cleartextAgainFile);

            while ((i = cis.read(block)) != -1) {
                fos.write(block, 0, i);
            }
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:
SunEC
EC
provider=SunJCE version 1.7
SunJCE version 1.7
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key length: 91 bytes

Can you please help with ECC curve and Algorithm to use

Comment: Are you sure the Java implementation you have supports the SEC 2 elliptic curve domain "sect163r2"?

Comment: Can you please help with ECC curve and Algorithm to use

Comment: why not use BouncyCastle library?

Answer (score 5):

From what I read, you are trying to:

- Generate a random key pair using ECC
- Use the ECC private key as a DES symmetric key for encryption
- Use the ECC public key as a DES symmetric key for decryption
- Expect the result to be a round-trip

This will not work -- DES is a symmetric algorithm; it requires that the same 56-bit key be used for encryption and decryption. Throwing an ECC key at it won't magically make it accept a different key for the two operations!

Comment: Can you please help with ECC curve and Algorithm to use
I just want to write a simple program in JDK 1.7 using ECC and I want to use ECC as a Keygenerator

Answer (score 2):

As duskwuff already pointed out you can not mix-up Elliptic curve with DES encryption.

The problem is that the new SunEC provider does [only implement Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) and Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunEC).

The encryption standard using EC would be [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme (ECIES)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) - which is not implemented in Java 7. Therefore you can not use EC for encryption without using an external library.

Comment: Thanks Robert :)
But in java 7 security enhancement it mentions that it has provider for ECC.
Also Can i use ECDH for encryption in that case

Comment: If ECDH really works you should be able to create a cipher instance from it: Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECDH");

Comment: By far I understand that I can use ECC for signature but not for encryption and decryption is it correct

Comment: Yes, that seems not possible with plain Java 7 at the moment.

Comment: @Akash: Note that you can use ECDH for *key agreement*, which will allow you to use a symmetric cipher. If you don't understand what that is, please pick up an introductory text to cryptography.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use ECDH to exchange a secret, symmetric key that you can then use for encrypting and decrypting DES.